Подключение к mssql server с помощью Python
для собственных целей мне требуется подключиться к mssql с помощью python, для этого воспользовался документацией мелкомягких. Вставил данный код и поменял на свои данные, но у меня появляется ошибка:
pymssql.exceptions.OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DESKTOP-SHP1V26)\nDB
По тексту ошибки я так понимаю, что я ввёл, что-то неправильно. Вот мой код:


import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(
    server='DESKTOP-SHP1V26\SQLEXPRESS',
    user='DayvioN,
    password='DayvioN',
    database='Albion',
    as_dict=True
)



Название сервера я взял то, которое пишется при подключении к ядру
Пользователя я создал нового и дал одинаковые логин и пароль
Сама база данных прям так и называется Albion
Подскажите что не так я сделал
